# What tags are created by nobody?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process

Users with 1500 reputation [can create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). The creator will be shown at the tag page, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node-async/info):

> **Stats**
>   created   2 years ago by SalmanPK
>   viewed    9 times
>   active    10 months ago
>   editors   2

You can earn the taxonomist badge for this as well. However, some tags don't have any creator, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async.js/info) - which just shows

> **Stats**
>   created   2 years ago
>   …

Who created those tags? Why don't they have a "created by" stat? What exactly makes a user a "tag creator"?

Comment: @GrantWinney: I created the tag wiki, yes, but not the tag itself. If you check the first example, wiki and excerpt were created by JamesAllardice, while SalmanPK is the "tag creator".

Comment: Yeah, I start to remember it was me who created the tag. However, another example: the [javascript tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info). Tag wiki creation and tag creation timestamp are the same even, but Shog doesn't show up as the creator.

Comment: [According to the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/285600), some tags are "community owned" (see the last column). But I don't how nor when it happens.

Comment: Also asked on MSE: [Why do some tag info pages show who created them and others don't?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/318296/289905).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The tag wiki page will only display a username next to the creation date if the [Taxonomist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) has been awarded to a user for that tag ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247148)).

Some very old tags never had users stored for them, and there are various things that can happen to a tag that will cause them not to have users associated with them. As well, since a user can only earn the Taxonomist badge once, if they create multiple tags, only one of those tags will ever have their name next to it.

Comment: That's delightfully weird.

Comment: Oh wow. And I thought it would be something simple as "tag creator only shows up if he's not the initial author of the tag wiki".

Comment: @GrantWinney The users listed in the revision history are the creators of the **tag wiki**, not the tag itself.