# How do I check who created a tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-creation-process

I can see the time when a tag was created. But is there a way to know who created the tag?

I want to know who created one of the most popular [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag.

Comment: By curiosity I suppose ? Or is there something else ?

Comment: Just curious about that. He would be a great man who created that tag

Comment: Great man ? It could also be any kind of beginner to be honest. It just require something like 2000 rep to create a tag, so basically, the first person who discover the technologie and notice it's not yet a tag on SO is a candidate. Maybe a genius, maybe just a quick thinking shooter. You know, if you search for great enthusiast programmer, there is https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet and other high rep user

Comment: Well; 1,183,255 questions is not a small amount:)

Comment: I don't know how you can think that creating the tag gives you any credit for the questions that use it. Is he actually proud of creating the tag ? maybe. But yeah ! impressive numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When exactly a tag was created is not always recorded for tags created before July 2010, not directly. You can find out, usually, but it takes a bit of work, and with deleted posts, not possible for anyone without moderator level access.

The [tag wiki page for a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) lists when the tag itself was created, in the top-right corner. For newer tags, if the creator [earned a taxonomy badge for the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287900), that information includes the author. For example, the [androidstudio-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/androidstudio-settings) tag [was created by William Kinaan](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info):

> created 5 years, 10 months ago by [William Kinaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1378388/william-kinaan)

However, tag wikis didn't get added to Stack Overflow until [July 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/01/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/). For tags that were created *before* that date, or when the tag creator already earned their Taxonomy badge for something else, then the *created* tag only lists a relative date:

> created 10 years, 7 months ago

There is a ISO8601 timestamp displayed when you hover over the text, but that's the *tag **wiki** creation date*, so the wiki page for the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag was created on 2010-07-22 10:36:15Z, but the tag itself is older. At best you can use the relative date to get an approximate starting date. Yes, this is confusing, and [reported as a bug over on Uber Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297857/tag-wiki-stats-created-showing-with-wrong-date-calculation). So the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag was created roughly in July or August 2008.

For newer tags, the tag wiki history can still give you the exact time the tag was created as at that exact time the Community user creates the initial empty tag wiki revision. You could then try to find the matching post where the tag was first used, provided it still exists!

For the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag, [only 4 still undeleted questions using the tag were created by the end of August 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20created%3a..2008-08-31%20%5bandroid%5d&mixed=0); in actual fact, the first question to ever use the tag was posted on the 13th of August 2008 but has since been deleted ([10k+ only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256/how-should-i-get-started-with-android-development)). Still, in all probability the tag was created by [Haydar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288/haydar). We just can’t be 100% sure, because in those early days some questions were hard-deleted and even us moderators can’t see those anymore.

Comment: Weird… 2010-07-22 10:36:15Z wasn’t 10 years and 7 months ago.

Comment: @Xufox: ah! I suspect the tag creation date, and tag wiki creation date are being mixed there.

Comment: I checked on Stackoverflow YouTube a few months ago that it's now more than 10 years old. Great.

Comment: @smileycreations15: there is no such revision for the android tag, however, because tag wikis are a newer addition  Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's 2020, I still don't find an easy way to check who created a tag or if I create a tag does it show somewhere in my profile?